# How can i properly install (in SEO perspective) 404 Error redirect to .php page

Tags: php, .htaccess, seo, http-status-code-404, custom-error-pages

I've made a custom 404.php page and tried to make a properly installed 404 redirect in .htaccess.

```
ErrorDocument 400 /400/index.php
ErrorDocument 401 /401/index.php
ErrorDocument 403 /403/index.php
ErrorDocument 404 /404/index.php
ErrorDocument 405 /405/index.php
ErrorDocument 408 /408/index.php
ErrorDocument 414 /414/index.php
ErrorDocument 500 /500/index.php
ErrorDocument 501 /501/index.php
ErrorDocument 502 /502/index.php
ErrorDocument 503 /503/index.php
ErrorDocument 504 /504/index.php
```

It works fine and i see my 404 page, when trying to type incorrect links.

But, when i use different website analyzers or seo checkers, i see the same issue with not properly installed 404 page:
[Not properly installed 404 page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MYlir.png)
[Not properly installed 404 page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H0DTB.png)

404.php page with this code before <!Doctype>

```
<?php
header('HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found');
header("Status: 404 Not Found");
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
session_start();
```

What can i do wrong? Hosting technical support told me, that everything is properly installed on their side, but they can't help with SEO questions. Thanks in advance

Comment: [Pictures of code](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode) or of [exceptions](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/) are not very helpful. Put a [mcve] and (if applicable) text of the exception in the question itself. The editor has buttons and [instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) to help you format it so it is readable.

Comment: The error seems pretty clear that you need to send your 404 pages with a 404 status and not a 200 status. We can't see the code you use to send your 404 pages (because you failed to share it) so its hard to tell why the status code is wrong.

Comment: I am sorry, i'll put code here

Comment: The screenshots from this checker tool are also not very helpful. We don't know which tool that is, nor what URL you actually gave it to check.

Comment: _"404.php page with this code"_ - Did you mean `/404/index.php` or do you actually have a `404.php` as well? How does your application work? Are you using a front controller with a router, or are you accessing the php-files directly? There are too many unknowns here.

Comment: I've just found the mistake, i'll reply to my question. Thanks everyone for trying to help!

Answer (score -4):

I've just found a solution. Website for 404 error checker https://websiteadvantage.com.au/404-Error-Handler-Checker
gave me such result:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/7JRXC.png

The problem was in firstly redirecting a page, and only then sending a

```
http_response_code(404);
```

So i put this:

```
function noPageFound($domain) {
        http_response_code(404);
        echo"<html><head><meta http-equiv='Refresh' content='0; ....>"; exit();
    }
```

And deleted 404 response code in 404.php page, as it was not neccessary.

```
    <?php
header('HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found');
header("Status: 404 Not Found");
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
session_start();
```

And the result was perfect. Thanks everyone.

Comment: you shouldn't redirect.

Comment: There must be "something else" going on here, since none of this should be necessary, given the code you've posted in the question. The Apache `ErrorDocument` directive would already send the correct 404 response status by default. If you are seeing a 301 redirect (as stated in your _screenshot_) then something else is doing that?! Why are you returning a meta-refresh in the HTML of your 404 (I assume) document??

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).